# How do I have a picture act as a game character on top of a canvas?

Tags: java, canvas, maze

I have a maze game in JAVA I'm doing for a class, the maze is made on a canvas in an applet, I wanted to have another picture provided to me (of a statue like thing) act as a game character and be able to be moved around the maze by the arrow keys, so how do I place an object on a canvas that can move around and be controlled, etc.? At the moment, the only way I could get my statue on the maze was by just copying the pixels of the picture onto the maze, so it's just part of the background now...Please help me! I've been posting everywhere looking for help to no avail.

Comment: Use Swing. Create a JLabel. Add a picture to the JLabel. Add it to you container. There are many solutions. Can you pose some code?

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Above the ContentPane you will find that exists a GlassPane. It is the right place to add your statue picture without messing with the background.